# FCM onMessageReceived Returns blank message and title when the app is running

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

As you wrote in the title , when the application is closed it's working well and the `onMessageReceived` gets the message body and the title but if the app is in the foreground mode (running mode) the notifications can be sent but without message and title !

What to do please ?

The Code :

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        sendNotification(title,message);
    }
```

I know there are alot of issues published here in Stackoverflow but I've tried their solutions but the problem still exist !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Replace

```
String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body);
```

By

```
String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
```

What you used is for data payload that you set as key-value pair while sending a notification. You may find input fields for them under `Advanced Options` section  as `Custom Data` in firebase notification console.

Comment: Works, Thank you so much bro.