# Android NotificationCompat not show title and content

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]I used NotificationCompat to build notifications. It showed successfully but without title and content though i set them up

`NotificationCompat` is from `androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat`

```
 override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage?) {
        super.onMessageReceived(p0)
        p0?.let {
            it.notification?.let {
                val alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
                val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this as Context, "first")
                        .setContentTitle("My title")
                        .setContentText("My content")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ebike_icon)
                        .setSound(alarmSound)
                        .setColor(Color.RED)
                        .setColorized(true)
                (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager)
                        .notify(1, builder.build())
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger in these lines?

Comment: And have other attributes been set right? Did you hear a sound and saw a picture?

Comment: Yeah, I debugged line by line. It run through all. There are sounds. Just the title and content disappear.

Comment: Sorry, do you really wrote "My title", but not `remoteMessage.data["title"]` as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019915/fcm-onmessagereceived-returns-blank-message-and-title-when-the-app-is-running? I had a similar problem with empty title because of silent push notifications.

Comment: Can you show us the payload you are sending through firebase and tell us how you are sending it-through firebase console or using the REST endpoint? Also, is this issue occurring only when the app is in the background? I suspect this might be the case.

Comment: @CoolMind. Yes, I really hardcoded "My title" but still it didn't appear.

Comment: @DerrylThomas I sent it via Rest endpoint (legacy) and this issue occurred both when the app is in background and foreground. I thought it might be related to androidx package since the snippet run well with support v4 lib

Comment: @HoangVietNguyen, very strange. Did you test on other devices? Probably you should check other tutorials and after that write your solution. At least, I cloned other repositories and understood how it worked.

Comment: Yes, very strange! Especially since OP says icon, color, sound etc is working as expected.
For android versions from Oreo upwards, you need to also set a notification channel.
@HoangVietNguyen, can you try adding this too?

Comment: @DerrylThomas I tried but not success. Anyway, I used android.app.Notification class instead of NotificationCompat to build notification and it worked.